# Do data member addresses lie between (this) and (this+1)?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Suppose that we have the following two inequalities inside a  member function

```
this <=  (void *) &this->data_member
```

and

```
&this->data_member < (void *) (this+1)
```

Are they guaranteed to be true? 
(They seem to be true in a few cases that I checked.)

Edit: I missed ampersands, now it's the correct form of inequalities.

Comment: Is the data_member a pointer?

Comment: What would be your plans if a particular C++ compiler uses, for example, one past the end of the actual object as the actual memory pointer value for the object?

Comment: @ Öö Tiib , No ampersands were missing, now it's corrected.

Comment: I'd assume you mean  `this <= (void *)(&this->data_member)` and `(void *)(&this->data_member) < (void *)(this + 1)`.    In any event, the standard only specifies results of comparison operators applied to members.  `this` is not a member, and nothing is said about the relationship between `this` and the address of its non-static members  i.e. the behaviour is not specified.   Practically, it would probably take some pretty funky bookkeeping to access non-static struct or class members if the members weren't laid out in memory pointed to by `this`.

Comment: It's not hard to see a counterexample in the wild if `data_member` is actually a data member of a virtual base.

Comment: @T.C.  I tried to produce a counterexample with a virtual base, but I failed so far. Could you please show it?

Comment: @user10636819 [here you go](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e27afb7d5fdad711)

Comment: @Caleth Thanks, that's a nice example. It's also a bit odd, since these inequalities seem to be satisfied once again, if tested directly inside struct D, rather than by calling member functions of base classes. I'm still learning C++ (and don't understand the virtual inheritance yet), but I guess this implies an  undefined behavior.

Comment: @user10636819 `sizeof(D)` is not `sizeof(B) + sizeof(C)`, because it only has one `A` base. There's some funkiness to allow conversion from a `D*` to a `B*` which is probably implemented by the representation of `B` only having a pointer to it's `A` base.

Comment: It would help if you say if you care only complete objects and array members, or arbitrary subobjects.

Comment: @user10636819 "_and don't understand the virtual inheritance yet_" Regular inheritance is an exclusive relation like membership. Virtual inheritance is a shared inheritance relation, so it's very different. Virtual inheritance is like virtual function, it can be overridden (in a way): it means that the inheritance relation between B and A is overridden in D. So B in D is not constructed like a complete B object. **Without virtual inheritance, a base class is constructed like a complete object.**

Answer (score 5):

From CPP standard draft 4713:

> **6.6.2 Object model [intro.object]/7**
>   An object of trivially copyable or standard-layout type (6.7) shall occupy contiguous bytes of storage.
>
> **12.2 Class members [class.mem]/18**
>    Non-static data members of a (non-union) class with the same access control (Clause 14) are allocated so that later members have higher addresses within a class object.
>
> **12.2 Class members [class.mem]/25**
>   If a standard-layout class object has any non-static data members, its address is the same as the address of its ﬁrst non-static data member. Otherwise, its address is the same as the address of its ﬁrst base class subobject (if any).

Taking all the above together, we can say the first equation holds for at least trivially copyable objects.

Also from the online [cpp reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison):

> The result of comparing two pointers to objects (after conversions) is defined as follows:
>
> 1) If two pointers point to different elements of the same array, or to subobjects within different elements of the same array, the pointer to the element with the higher subscript compares greater. In other words, they results of comparing the pointers is the same as the result of comparing the indexes of the elements they point to.
>   2) If one pointer points to an element of an array, or to a subobject of the element of the array, and another pointer points one past the last element of the array, the latter pointer compares greater. **Pointers to single objects are treated as pointers to arrays of one: `&obj+1` compares greater than `&obj`** (since C++17)

So if your `data_member` is **not** a pointer and has not been allocated memory separately, the equations you have posted hold good 
for at least trivially copyable objects.

Comment: The subtlety, and the problem, is that a program cannot generally test it itself, because then the behavior would be undefined.

Comment: @StoryTeller How is your statement related to the question or the answer?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider - Directly from the question: *"They seem to be true in a few cases that I checked"*. How do you envision the OP checking it?

Comment: Thanks! So this guarantees that the second inequality holds. What about the first one (it compares members of the object with its own address)?

Comment: @user10636819:  *"If a standard-layout class object has any non-static data members, its address is the same as the address of its ﬁrst non-static data member."* and *"Non-static data members of a (non-union) class with the same access control  are allocated so that later members have higher addresses within a class object. "*. Taken together this would mean that the first one is also true.

Comment: @StoryTeller The boolean result of the comparison is `true`, which is trivial to check within the program. This has nothing to do with whether the program is correct or not, and even less with the program cecking itself. (If the OP succeeded in *that* he would immediately get an offer from the Laundry which he couldn't refuse ;-).)

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider - The boolean result of this expression is unspecified by the standard, I don't know what your definition of "correct" is, mine when approaching this starts with whether or not the standard gives us the specification to reason about it. If we can't reason about it in a truly portable way, discussing "correctness" is pointless.

Comment: @StoryTeller You said "that a program cannot generally test it itself", and while this is true, it has no relation to the question or the answer: In both cases *we humans* try to establish whether the program is valid C++, and if so, whether it has defined behavior, and if so, whether this behavior is specified. At no point is the program trying to test itself.-- As to the defined-ness, specified-ness and correctness, I side with P.W. in that the program is all three.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider - Nobody sided *against* P.W. And I refuse to be dragged down this rabbit hole. You still don't see how my comment is related? Well, that's just too bad I guess. Good day.

Comment: @StoryTeller You said "The boolean result of this expression is unspecified by the standard" which appears to contradict P.W.'s conclusion "the equations you have posted hold good", unless I'm misreading one of you.

Comment: Having the same address doesn't guarantee it has equivalent partial ordering when casted to `void*`. `this` doesn't point to a non-static data member and therefore result of the comparison is unspecified. There is no special clause for standard-layout types.

Answer (score 4):

The full [standard text](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.rel#4) amounts to this:

> **[expr.rel] - 4:** The result of comparing unequal pointers to objects<sup>82</sup> is defined in terms of a **partial order** consistent with the following rules:

We are dealing with a partial order here, not a total order. That does mean `a < b` and `b < c` implies `a < c`, but not much else.

(Note 82 states that non-array objects are considered elements of a single-element array for this purpose, with the intuitive meaning/behavior of "pointer to element one past the end").

> (4.1)
>       If two pointers point to different elements of **the same array**, or to subobjects thereof, the pointer to the element with the higher subscript is required to compare greater.

Pointers to different members are not pointers to (subobjects of) elements of the same array. This rule does not apply.

> (4.2)
>       If two pointers point to different non-static data members of **the same object**, or to subobjects of such members, recursively, the pointer to the later declared member is required to compare greater provided the two members have the same access control ([class.access]), neither member is a subobject of zero size, and their class is not a union.

This rule only relates pointers to data members of the same object, not of a different object.

> (4.3)
>       Otherwise, neither pointer is required to compare greater than the other.

Thus, you do not get any guarantees from the standard. Whether you can find a real-world system where you get a different result than you expect is another question.

Comment: I would just add that for _standard layout classes_, a pointer to its instance/object can be reinterpretted as a pointer to its first non-static member variable. And all other member variables must be stored at greater adresses. Which implies that both OP's conditions are guaranteed to be true, but only in this special case.

Comment: Also, for _trivially copyable classes_, all data members must be stored between a pointer to the object and the same increased by its size in bytes (which implies the same). Otherwise, we wouldn't be allowed to `memcpy` such objects.

Comment: That would have been my off-the-cuff answer ("unrelated objects, no guarantees"); but when we consider the "single objects are equivalent to arrays of size 1" plus "1-past-last is defined as greater" we arrive, I believe, at P.W.'s answer, because "&x+1" is not "unrelated" but one-past-array, to wich 4.1 applies.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider What if for a non-standard-layout non-trivially-copyable class a pointer to its instance would be internally defined as an address of its last byte in memory. Is there anything in the Standard that forbids such an impelementation?

Comment: @DanielLangr A pointer to an object (i.e. a chunk of typed memory) *always* points to its first byte. [Also: How would you "internally define"?] Not sure I can quote a standard location for that; but to violate this basic idea seems to wreck havoc on a number of invariants (`::free(void *)`!?). It is not guarenteed what we find there, and the OP's assumptions are only correct for non-static, well, *data-members*, but I don't see a requirement for "trivially-copyable" or "standard-layout". [ctd.]

Comment: [ctd.:]  12.2/17 in n4659 flatly says "Non-static data members of a (non-union) class with the same access control (Clause 14) are allocated so that later members have higher addresses **within a class object** (emphasis by me). There's little to discuss here.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider This may be extremely pedantic, but where does the standard specify what "first" means in _"its address is the same as the address of its ﬁrst non-static data member"_? Of course we all know what is meant, but does it elaborate anywhere?

Comment: @MaxLanghof The pedantic answer is, of course: It's the element whose address coincides with the address of the object. ;-) But more seriously: There is a guarantee that the elements are layed out in the order of their declaration (as opposed e.g. to function parameter evaluation which is, IIRC, unspecified).

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider That guarantee only exists for data members of the same access level. In particular, it is unspecified whether your `private` members come before the `public` ones or the other way around. Thus I could take pedantism to the extreme and say "first" always means "private members", even though private members have higher pointer values than public ones in my implementation.

Comment: @DanielLangr "_would be internally defined as an address_" What do you mean "internally"? The representation of a pointer is an implementation detail: you can't reinterpret a pointer as another pointer type and expect anything sensible. You could have pointers to a 8 bytes aligned type that have the 3 lowest bit set for the fun, but always masked out when dereferenced. You would only see these bits set via type-punning or representation examination (`reinterpret_cast<void**>`, union, `memcpy`) or maybe `reinterpret_cast<int>`.

Comment: IOW, can the internally defined address be measured with a construct with a well defined result? What would implicitly converting to `void*` or `reinterpret_cast<char*>` of these pointers do? Would the result point to the last byte, or would that be changed to hide the "internal representation"?

Comment: "_What if for a non-standard-layout non-trivially-copyable class_" a class called `T` "_a pointer to its instance would be internally defined as an address of its last byte in memory_" What would happen to such code? `void *raw = operator new(sizeof T); T *p = new(raw) T; p->~T(); operator delete(/*note: not raw*/ p);`

Comment: @curiousguy Agree, that was likely not a valid example. Just a note: wouldn't `delete p;` be undefined behavior here? An argument of `operator delete` can be only a pointer obtained by the `operator new`, which is `raw` here.

Comment: @DanielLangr I have never consider the possibility that `new(raw) T != raw`.

Answer (score 0):

The value of an object is within its representation, and this representation is a sequence of unsigned char: [[basic.types]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#4)

> The object representation of an object of type T is the sequence of N unsigned char objects taken up by the object of type T, where N equals sizeof(T).
>   The value representation of an object of type T is the set of bits that participate in representing a value of type T.[...]

So for formalism fundamentalists, it is true that *value* is not defined but the term appears in the definition of *access*:[[defns.access]](http://eel.is/c++draft/defns.access):

> read or modify the value of an object

So is the value of a suboject part of the value of a complete object? I suppose this is what is intended by the standard.

The comparison should be true if you cast object pointers to `unsigned char*`. (This is a common practice that falls on an under-specification [core issue #1701](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#1701))

Comment: Yes for any **complete** object.

Comment: @curiousguy You mean type?

Comment: You can't even do pointer arithmetic on an incomplete type pointer, AFAIK, so no `p+1`. I mean complete object.

Comment: There is no incomplete object! See [intro.object](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#1.sentence-2). But indeed if a reference or pointer is to an incomplete type, there are not much things that can be done with it.

Comment: What do you mean by "complete object"?

Comment: "_Yes for any complete object_" I meant that "The object representation of an object of type T..." should read "complete object". [basic.types]/4 is not correct here (IMNSHO)

Comment: "_An object is created by a definition, by a new-expression ([expr.new]), when implicitly changing the active member of a union, or when a temporary object is created ([conv.rval], [class.temporary])_" So you agree that every textbook ever written on C++ is wrong, Stroustrup is wrong, the std is wrong WRT converting C programs to C++ (lol). Do you really want to stand by that claim? Legal lawyer never meant to take the text seriously against every other source on C++.

Comment: Also, "when implicitly changing the active member of a union" was NOT present for more than a DECADE. So anyone takes that sentence seriously? Really? It's soooo wrong! Also, "An object is created by a definition," doesn't even compute as a definition is a syntax construct and an object exist at runtime. It could have said evaluation but I'm not sure definitions are "evaluated". This is bad standardese!

Comment: @curiousguy You make me remimber myself before I was formated by having read to much the standard. I think I have adopted this "existentialist" use of the verb "to be" for objects (In the standard when it is written ... there is an object. It means the object was constructed and neither destroyed nor its storage released). But whatsoever it is possible to have an expression whose refered type is incomplete: the object is created in a translation unit where the type is complete and then referred in an other translation unit where the type is incomplete in which case as you say,

Comment: "_it is possible to have an expression whose refered type is incomplete_" Clearly yes. There was no disagreement on that.

Answer (score 0):

No, here's a counterexample

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int a_member[10];    
};

struct B : public virtual A
{
    int b_member[10];
    void print_b() { std::cout << static_cast<void*>(this) << " " << static_cast<void*>(std::addressof(this->a_member)) << " " << static_cast<void*>(this + 1) << std::endl; }
};

struct C : public virtual A
{
    int c_member[10];    
    void print_c() { std::cout << static_cast<void*>(this) << " " << static_cast<void*>(std::addressof(this->a_member)) << " " << static_cast<void*>(this + 1) << std::endl; }
};

struct D : public B, public C 
{
    void print_d() 
    { 
        print_b();
        print_c();
    }
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    d.print_d();
}
```

With the possible output (as [seen here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e27afb7d5fdad711))

```
0x7fffc6bf9fb0 0x7fffc6bfa010 0x7fffc6bfa008
0x7fffc6bf9fe0 0x7fffc6bfa010 0x7fffc6bfa038
```

Note that the `a_member` is outside of the `B` pointed to by `this` in `print_b`

Comment: And treating such base subobject as an array element (as an imaginary array of one element) doesn't really make sense. Not sure it should be legal.